# How do I advertise for volunteers for my open source project

Tags: open-source, contribution

I have found a couple of related questions here on programmers.SE:

[How/where would I best advertise my open source project, in order to maximize my odds of finding collaborators?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126423/how-where-would-i-best-advertise-my-open-source-project-in-order-to-maximize-my)

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60830/where-to-find-open-source-volunteers

My question is slightly different because I am primarily looking for non-coders to help with a few things in my new open source project. In particular, I'd like one or more people to create an icon and other graphics and to work on a web site, wiki pages, and/or other documentation.

My project is a front-end for a baseball card database. So reaching out to baseball card collectors might be useful. Other than that, I would just like anyone who would like to contribute in small ways to a modest project. Where are some good places to advertise and find non-coder volunteers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of many topics covered in [Producing Open Source Software](http://producingoss.com/en/index.html) - a free (e)book by Karl Fogel.

If you want to lead an open source project and make it successful, this is very good place to start. It focuses mostly on the people side of a project and on how to present the project to the world.